# Axon EventHandlers in TrackingEventProcessors were not invoked

Tags: axon

A few days ago a client mentioned us an entity couldn't be found, although our system returned a 202, meaning the request was processed successfully.
The request was processed successfully as events caused by the command due to the request can be found in the EventStore.

What's so weird about this issue is all the tracking processors were **not** invoked on the events caused by the first request.
On subsequent events the tracking processors were throwing exceptions as the entity couldn't be found in the database.
So the eventhandlers for the events from the first command were not invoked, but for subsequent commands, events were invoked.

What could have been possibly gone wrong with the events from the first command, as the tracking processors were not invoked?

Our setup is running 2 axon instances connected to 1 PostgreSQL database.
The processors are backed by JPA and JDBC repositories.

Below a simplified snapshot of the events in the EventStore:

| global_index | payload_type | timestamp | aggregate_id | sequence_number | my conclusions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8219359 | Aggregate1CreatedEventDueToRequest1 | 2021-02-08T16:25:33.763048105Z | 1 | 0 |  |
| 8235842 | Aggregate2CreatedEventDueToRequest0 | 2021-02-08T17:12:28.036313918Z | 2 | 0 | Not handled by TPs |
| 8235843 | Aggregate2Event2DueToRequest1 | 2021-02-08T17:12:28.036338611Z | 2 | 1 | Not handled by TPs, but handles by Subscribing Processor |
| 8235844 | Aggregate2Event3DueToRequest1 | 2021-02-08T17:12:28.03635331Z | 2 | 2 | Not handled by TPs |
| 8235845 | Aggregate2Event4DueToRequest1 | 2021-02-08T17:12:28.036372834Z | 2 | 3 | Not handled by TPs |
| 8235847 | Aggregate1Event2DueToAggregate2Event2DueToRequest1 | 2021-02-08T17:12:28.045952574Z | 1 | 1 |  |
| 8235848 | Aggregate1Event3DueToAggregate2Event2DueToRequest1 | 2021-02-08T17:12:28.04599099Z | 1 | 2 |  |
| 8235849 | Aggregate1Event4DueToAggregate2Event2DueToRequest1 | 2021-02-08T17:12:28.04608497Z | 1 | 3 |  |
| 8235850 | Aggregate2Event5DueToRequest2 | 2021-02-08T17:12:28.058377074Z | 2 | 4 | Handled by TPs, but exceptions as previous events not handled |

Comment: Could you specify which version of Axon Framework you are using?
Did you configure any `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler`?
In the table containing the (summary) of events, it would be helpful to also see the "global sequence" numbers.

Comment: @Allard currently we are on `4.3.5` and we have a `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler` configured for the subscribing eventprocessor, not for the tracking eventprocessors.

Comment: Issue also happened when replaying a TP, with default batch-size and segments.

Comment: Hi Tom, sorry for the follow ups, but when you say "also happened when replaying a TP", does that mean it happens consistently and at the same point?

Comment: Also, the "gap" between 8219359 and 8235842, is that because there are no events part of the two aggregates described, or aren't there any events at all?

Comment: No, it's not happening consistently.
Only a few aggregates we missing in the read models.
And the "gap" is because of other aggregate events.

Comment: What isolation level is configured on the DB system?
Preferably, Read Committed.